# Add the same multiplier to one object

Tags: modifiers, boolean-modifier

I'm sort new to blender, just discovering and set off to modelling something of my own, best way to learn a software for me rather than just following tutorials. While working on this part I was wondering whether there is a way to automate adding the same multiplier to one object multiple times. In this case I'm making a bracket and for the screw holes I'm using Boolean. However since there are many holes its kind of cumbersome going 1 by one and its taking a silly amount of time. I am more used with CAD and parametric software (such as grasshopper on Rhinoceros) so I'm wondering if there is a better way to do this bracket.

[image]

Comment: if i may give you a hint: you should definetely not try to find out everything on your own with Blender, because it doesn't work intuitive at all. You should watch tutorials because your learning curve will be multiple times steeper. Blender is neither always logic nor working in the same way (just it works on one way with that modifier doesn't mean it works on the other e.g.) so...if you don't want to get frustrated you should watch tutorials. Blender is really an amazing great software but...i think it needs tutorials to learn it.

Answer (score 0):

You can put the objects that you are going to cut with into a single collection and use that collection as the operand type for the boolean modifier.

[image]

[image]

(Remember to use Shade (Auto Smooth) after using the boolean or else it will give you some wierd shading artifacts)

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I'll try it and seems like a more efficient way than what I did! ^^